Can’t boot windows in AHCI

Hi I follower al the guide ti boot windows with AHCI as controller type. I was using the command prompt to boot windows beacause it fibra me an error and I couldn’t une any of the bcdedit repair command. So I use the Bcdboot command but I can’t manually select the boot volume that is normally named “F” because in the list volume it doesn’t give me the letter of that volume. How can I fix that?

Here is the command prompt:
(in the volume 1 it doesn’t give me any letters)
Volume 0   C   Windows-SSD
Volume 1       SYSTEM_DRV
Volume 2   D   WINRE_DRV


use diskpart command to assign a letter to the volume. diskpart, lis vol, sel vol x, assign letter=y, and exit. replace x with the volume number and y with the letter you want to assign.

BCDBoot is a command-line tool used to configure the boot files on a PC or device to run the Windows operating system.
